# Безопасность куки

Tags: javascript, cookie, безопасность

Объясните пожалуйста почему куки считают не безопасными? Я думаю что это вполне себе безопасная вещь, я просто хочу убедится в этом. Куки по подсунутой ссылке с нужного сайта никак не вытащить. Способы запустить на компе клиента сниффер тоже для этого вопроса отпадают потому что на комп нужно залезть, чтобы взять куку пользователя на нужном злоумышленнику сайте JS код должен выполнится именно на этом сайте, а это уже взломать сам хостинг. В общем случае кука для двух удаленных друг от друга людей где один хочет стащить куку у другого это вполне безопасная вещь.
Если клиенту подсунуть ссылку на бесплатный хостинг где выполнится document.cookie и отправится на кому нужно через ajax, то куки всех сайтов не отправятся, отправится кука того домена куда попал клиент.

Взломать хостинг, залезть на комп клиента не относится к вопросу, в остальном (подсунуть ссылку) и все что угодно кроме двух условий выше можно, в таком варианте кука вполне безопасна разве нет?

Comment: Где вы прочитали что их считают небезопасными?

Comment: Кука безопасна при условии, что ее ставит сервер (а не браузер через javascript) с включенными флагами secure и httponly и сайт работает только по протоколу https. При приеме куки на сервере ее нужно проверять, так как она может содержать совершенно не те данные, которые вы ожидаете.

Comment: tutankhamun, честно говоря я просто наслышан что все ругают кукпи просто от общего мнения, и мнения друзей, а из статей вот, https://habrahabr.ru/post/272187/, я просто хочу убедится что куки просто так никак не получится получить, чтобы это просто подтвердили и действительно нет никаких уязвимостей в общем простом случае, и еще вот http://www.softtime.ru/forum/read.php?id_forum=4&id_theme=64900, но это же просто стащить куки с самого же сайта хостером :)

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос "безопасны ли cookies" некорректен. Сами по себе cookies не несут никакой угрозы.

Безопасна или уязвима может быть та или иная **схема их использования**.

Например, какая-то конкретная реализация системы аутентификации или авторизации, использующая cookies, вполне может быть небезопасна. Здесь как раз есть множество распространенных ошибок, которые совершают разработчики, используя cookies. Из-за этих ошибок и появляются уязвимости в **системах, использующих cookies** (а не в cookies самих по себе).

В [упомянутой вами статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/272187/) никоим образом не утверждается, что "куки плохие и небезопасные", и не предлагается отказаться от них. В этой статье рассматривается конкретные случаи ошибок и недочетов **в реализациях систем, работающих с cookies**. А совокупность тех или иных недостатков уже и создает уязвимость, которую можно эксплуатировать.

---

Теперь по поводу типовых угроз.

Вы приводите доводы в пользу того, что вытащить куки не так-то просто.

Во-первых, чтобы выполнить JS на сайте не обязательно "взламывать хостинг". Зачастую для этого достаточно найти [XSS-уязвимость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3), техник огромное множество.

*Совет: использование [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) значительно облегчает защиту от XSS, CSSI, кликджекинга.*

---

Действительно, как упомянул [Константин Алексеев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/tutankhamun), полезно использовать httpOnly-куки, для тех случаев, когда доступ из JS не нужен, чтобы, даже если вдруг будет выполнен вредоносный скрипт, он не имел доступ к значению куки.

Но, опять же, это не является 100% защитой от прочтения куки. Информация о куке с флагом "httpOnly" приходит в http-заголовке. Если сайт подвержен [HTTP Response Splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting), ответ от сервера может быть модифицирован (чтобы отключить флаг httpOnly), а старые значения кук сдвинуты в тело ответа. Вот [минималистичный пример](https://support.detectify.com/customer/portal/articles/2088184-http-response-splitting-hrs-).

---

Обратите внимание, что **опасна далеко не только кража cookies** с секретными данными.

С куками также связаны уязвимости [межсайтовой подделки запросов (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). В данном случае не предполагается "кража cookies": злоумышленнику достаточно каким-то из методов заставить браузер пользователя сделать тот или иной запрос к атакуемому серверу (а куки подставит уже сам браузер пользователя, знать их атакующему и не нужно). Если сервер подвержен уязвимости CSRF, то злоумышленник может выполнить от имени пользователя то или иное действие (покупка, изменение данных, пост), не узнавая значение самой куки.

Поэтому, при выполнении запросов на изменение какого-то состояния, cookies обычно используется вместе с csrf-токенами. Есть разные виды реализации защиты с csrf-токенами (в том числе иногда и не очень удачные: в приведенной вами статье с хабра показывалась уязвимость в схеме с double submit cookies, появившаяся вообще из-за особенностей сторонней системы).

Посмотрите также на такие уязвимости как [фиксация сессии](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation), которые косвенно тоже связаны с cookies, но не требуют их "воровства".

В конце концов даже какой-нибудь [SQLi](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)-вектор атаки злоумышленник может вставить прямо в значение cookies, вручную формируя запрос к вашему сайту. И, если вы не фильтруете/не экранируете содержимое cookies, а потом подставляете его в таком виде в строку sql-запроса, получается "небезопасно": может уйти база вашего ресурса, в каких-то случаях sqli приводят и к удаленному исполнению кода.

Виноваты ли в этом всём cookies? Нет. 
Но, как вы видите, расслабляться тоже нельзя, опасности поджидают буквально везде. :)

Answer (score 1):

В современных браузерах куки являются достаточно безопасным местом для хранения небольших порций данных если ваш сайт не подвержен XSS атакам. Кроме того есть возможность записать данные в куки, которые невозможно прочитать посредством Javascript.

Comment: абсолютно тоже так считаю, есть еще возможность отправлять куки после установки расширения в браузер но это тоже надо постараться, здесь уже любая кука уйдет куда нужно, для этого както сайты проверяют запрет на создание каталогов в папке extensions